# Custom Encryption using Application Level Add-In

Tags: c#, encryption, ms-office, office-interop

I am trying to develop an add-in to Word 2013 (using Visual Studio 2012) which will allow user's to use custom encryption to encrypt the document.

The resources on internet suggest that I need to implement an EncryptionProvider interface in a COM add-in. To develop COM add-in. This is typically done by using Shared Add-In template which used to come with Visual Studio 2010 but is no longer available in visual studio 2012; instead project templates for "Application Level Add-In" are provided in VS 2012.

So my question is - *Is it possible to implement custom encryption by implementing EncryptionProvider interface in Application Level Add-ins?*

If yes can someone shed some light on how that is to be done?

Comment: Hi, have you managed to do it ?